# Oracle Trigger: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if

Tags: oracle, select, if-statement, triggers

This is the code that produces that error:

```
create or replace trigger "T4"
AFTER
update of "VALORE" on "OFFERTA"
for each row 

DECLARE
     cs Inserzione.PrezzoF%TYPE;

BEGIN
    SELECT I.PrezzoF INTO cs
    FROM Inserzione I JOIN Offerta O ON I.Codice = O.Codice
    WHERE O.Codice = :old.Codice; 

    IF (cs!=NULL AND new.Valore >= cs) THEN
        UPDATE Inserzione
        SET Stato = 'OFF';
    ENDIF;
END;​
```

I don't understand why, because it seems correct. 
The error is: 13    4   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if

Comment: Use END IF; instead of ENDIF;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors.

The one that is throwing the error is, as @Multisync points out in the comments, that `ENDIF` should be `END IF`.

Beyond that, though, there are a couple of other issues.

1. `new.Valore` should be `:new.Valore`-- the `:new` and `:old` pseudorecords need to be prefixed with a colon.
2. `cs!=NULL` will always return `FALSE` even if `cs` is actually `NULL` (technically, it will always return "unknown" which will be interpreted as false).  You would need to use `cs IS NOT NULL` if you want to check to see if `cs` is `NULL`.
3. I'll strongly wager that your `UPDATE` statement is missing a `WHERE` clause-- I don't believe that you really want to update every row of the `Inserzione` table.  Most likely, you'd need to add `WHERE codice = :old.codice`.

Updated `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE Inserzione i
   SET Stato = 'OFF'
 WHERE i.codice = :old.codice;
```

4. You cannot generally `SELECT` from the table that the trigger is defined on in a row-level trigger.  That will generally raise a mutating table exception.  I suspect that the join to `offerta` in your `SELECT` statement isn't needed.  You probably just want something like

Updated `SELECT`

```
SELECT i.prezzoF
  INTO cs
  FROM inserzione i
 WHERE i.codie = :old.codice;
```